# Regarding the validity of probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, philosophy

Imagine I have a regular balanced dice and i roll it once. It is assumed that the probability of any number (1-6) is 1/6.

However, isn't this just an illusion we are feeding ourselves for our lack of knowledge regarding the environment and conditions under which the dice is thrown? If we could control the flick of the wrist throwing the dice, know all the characteristics of the surface on which the dice hits, control all the other variables involved, and we replicated the exact same circumstances, wouldn't we always get the same result?

My point is, can't we define Probabilities simply as the lack of knowledge/technology we have of a certain event, and that when (and if) we achieve the capability of controlling all variables in nature that this branch of Mathematics will be put aside as obsolete? That this field only exist as long as our knowledge is limited, and as such can't be considered a time-invariant "truth", as algebra or calculus is? That probabilities don't really exist in Nature, where there is cause-effect and not true randomness, and therefore is a simplification of reality that doesn't exist outside the human mind?

Comment: This might be interesting: [Applications of Probability Theory in pure mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4983/applications-of-probability-theory-in-pure-mathematics).

Comment: Well as long there is uncertainty in the world, probability is interesting and important. Though, I'll concede I didn't really understand what you were talking about.

Comment: Probability do make sense, unless you are able to control variable that exists (including those influencing the universe itself), which would mean that you are even able to predict the future. You took the example of rolling a dice which basically Depends on physics low, that if you are able to control them then you will be able to reproduce exactly the same result. But you can also consider "the time when you will die" as a random variable which is not so deterministic (unless you can predict future).

Comment: Mathematics is not about what we can do in real life. It is about mathematics. Any correlation between mathematics and the real world is purely coincidental.

Comment: @AsafKaragila All Mathematical knowledge is proven using logic that holds truth in the plane of existence we live in. Probabilities, i believe, is an over-simplification of reality and only exists due to our limited knowledge of all variables involved.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I beg to disagree. The development of mathematics has been profoundly influenced by real life, notably for money (astronomy etc) and war (trigonometry, trajectories). And it in its turn has profoundly influenced our world. And one might go further and say that true reality *is* the world of quantum mechanics which can *only* be understood mathematically. And after all that, voting to close :)

Comment: @Uracilo: Some will beg to differ, and tell you that the law of excluded middle doesn't hold in real life. Others will argue that since a lot of mathematics nowadays is based on infinite sets, it is plain false as infinite sets don't "exist" in reality.

Comment: @TooTone: You're confusing physics and economics with mathematics. The fact that my mom can only understand the world by thinking about it in Hebrew doesn't mean that Hebrew is necessary for understanding the world.

Comment: @Asaf "Any correlation between mathematics and the real world is purely coincidental." Hmmm... and yet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Unreasonable_Effectiveness_of_Mathematics_in_the_Natural_Sciences

Comment: @Did: I am not disputing the facts that mathematics is used quite successfully to describe all sort of things. But it is still coincidental in the sense that a lot of the mathematical theories were not developed for this purpose (and those that were often outgrew that purpose with some point).

Comment: @Asaf "a lot of the mathematical theories were not developed for this purpose" Quite so. But unplanned successes (in the sense of: unexpexted fertile applications of mathematical theories outside of the field of mathematics), especially when they are recurring, need explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you buy a high-quality die, like they use in Vegas, then saying "each side has a 1/6 probability of coming up" is not a statement of our lack of information about the die; on the contrary it is a statement of our knowledge of how symmetric and fair the die is.  A 10-cent die you buy in the grocery store might not be fair, but the really good ones are fair to anyone's ability to measure.

"If we could control ... wouldn't we always get the same result?"  The answer to that would seem to be yes, but the reality is that we simply cannot achieve that level of control.  Consider a die roll at a craps table in Vegas: the die travels a couple meters bounces a few times on a felt surface, and then comes to rest.  A tiny change in the angle of the die when it hits (eg. perfectly flat vs. slightly on the leading edge vs. slightly on the trailing edge) will yield a large change in the direction/spin of the die after it bounces.  Compound that by several bounces, and you get to the point where deviation by the width of an atom will change the result.

Clearly, we're way beyond what can be achieved with flesh and bone.  Even robots would fail to produce repeatable results due to variations in the airflow.  Maybe in a vacuum?  Maybe.  For this example.

If we wanted something more complicated, like "throw a die down a 50-foot hallway such that it bounces at least ten times on the carpet", then the accuracy required will pass the point where Quantum-Mechanical fluctuations would take over.  The result would be truly random.

Your comment "That probabilities don't really exist in Nature, where there is cause-effect and not true randomness," also fails to take into account QM.  Every time a radioactive particle decays, the timing of the decay and the directions taken by the decay products are both entirely random.  That information simply does not exist in this universe before the decay happens.  All those random events add up: If you had access to all the information that exists right now, you could not tell us where it will be raining one year from today.

Comment: I like your answer for taking into consideration QM, which i must admit, have limited knowledge of. I know that the level of technology it would take to accurately recreate a situation is tremendous and will almost certainly never happen. The QM definition proposed by Bohr is a good addition to your answer: "the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics is not a temporary feature which will eventually be replaced by a deterministic theory, but instead must be considered a final renunciation of the classical idea of "causality"."

Answer (score 0):

There are properties of sequences of random numbers that can be checked that have been checked for pseudo-random number generators, and the best pseudo-random number generators pass most of the tests. So the real question is if we neglect the nuances of the flick of the wrist, whether the sequence of random dice throws so generated will pass the checks for properties of sequences of random numbers that are sought after. To me, this is a question as to what kind of randomness is introduced into the flick of the wrist since we don't have $100\%$ complete control over how we flick our wrists. If that part can be considered "random" according to the desired properties of sequences of random numbers, then I suspect that the resulting dice throws will also pass the checks for properties of random sequences that are desired.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematics is not about nature ...
What if I tell you (in pure mathematics not in science that uses mathematics) that the probability of picking a square-free number from the integers is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$ ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer#Distribution

Will you say this is useless even if you are controlling what you call "all variables of nature" ?

Comment: That simply shows me the amount of integers between 1 and x that abide that rule, not the probability of something happening. Of course i accept that in the set {1,2,3} 33.333(3)% of the set is over 2, the real question is regarding the probability of something happening.

Comment: @Uracilo "Picking" a square-free number from the integers is an "action" that one can do. Therefore it may "happen". Also, dying is something that happens. Will you be able to get the exact time when someone will dye assuming that you have a full knowledge of all variables of physical nature ? Or will you just give a probability ?

Comment: Also, what if at the tome you roll a dice, someone "A" beside you "decide" to change/bias the surface on which the dice will fall. You can have a probability that "A" will reside to some external criteria, but you can never be sure (100%) that "A" will decide or not to change the surface on which the dice will fall.